# 2008 Subaru Outback (Base) EJ253 4EAT - Wheel Hub Assembly Questions

Tags: subaru

Replacing my Wheel Hub Assemblies with Moog PN#: 513220 Pre-Loaded Complete Assemblies.

**Unverified Torque Specs:**

- Hub-to-Knuckle Bolts: 47.9 ft-lb
- Front Axle Nut: 162 ft-lb
- Lug Nuts: 81.1 ft-lb (all)
- Caliper Bracket-to-Knuckle: 59 ft. lbs.
- Caliper Retainers: 19 ft. lbs.
- Rotor shield: 10 ft. lbs.

**My Questions:**

- Should I, or should I not Lubricate the Axle Spline before inserting it into the Hub Assembly?
- How can I ensure that the Hall Effect Sensor is clean? Can I wipe it off with clean rag?
- After removing the hub assembly, I need to surface, and clean the rust off what the Hub Assembly mounts to (the "Knuckle"). Will Brake Cleaner effect the sensor/"Magnetic Encoder"? Again, how do I ensure that the sensor is clean before putting the Hub Assembly back on?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just in case someone's planning this project, you'll want some cold-chisels of various sizes (1/4" -3/4"). It's likely that you'll need to wedge the hub assembly out of the knuckle due to rust. Reference the new knuckle for the area(s) where it's safe(r) to get the wedge/chisel in without damaging the "Casting" details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place a bit of non metallic anti-seize onto the splines. I would not recommend anti seize on the threads as it changes the nut-on-thread friction, thereby invalidating your torque values.

Should you be concerned about rust:
You could, after(!) tightening the nut, cover the axle nut and protruding bolt with some spray-on-wax. Ensure that the wax does not contaminates other parts (as the brake rotor)

The hall sensor should tolerate Brake Cleaner. If in doubt use a rag and pressurized air. If equipped, gently clean the abs ring on the CV joint, use brake cleaner there.

You need to clean the surface where the hub mounts to the steering knuckle. A stiff wire brush is the perfect tool for this.

To facilitate a future rotor removal cover the hub ring with some anti seize.